# Is there a Webrowser control equivalent in ASP.Net website forms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I am toying around with Visual Basic (via Visual Studio) to scrape data into desktop forms/apps, but I am looking to potentially do the same with an ASP.net website. Is this possible?

When just making stand alone forms I could previously just drop a WebBrowser into a form then declare the website and scrape. Something like this:

```vb
WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.somewebsite.com")
Label.Text =WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("name")(0).innerText
```

I just would like to be able to scrape again in website form. Could someone point me in the direction of the proper control/method? If the answer uses C#, I could probably figure it out that way too.

Comment: A WebBrowser is not really meant to be used in that way. It's more for using the UI that you get with it. There are better ways of interacting programatically with a webpage. Sending GET and POST requests in C# is fairly simple, and using tools like HTML Agility Pack to inspect the results is easy.

Comment: Thanks, I figured there'd be a better way. Know of any good tutorials in regards to this?